# How can I set a memory limit for a docker container created by visual studio code remote devcontainer configuration

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

**My configuration:**

- Laptop with VSCode (with VSCode remote development extension) & Docker Desktop.
- Server with Docker Host.
- My project locally just have: devcomposer.json, and a docker-compose.json.

**My process:**

- Open SSH tunnel to server.
- In VSCode I hit open in container (which builds the container).
- My remote development container builds fine, and I'm able to use everything there.

**My little PROBLEM:**

When running a simple chown over hugely populated folders, such as node_modules, the container memory requirements go mad, crashing not just the container, but my whole server....

**I've tried:**

1. Setting runArgs with:

   - ["-m","3g"]
   - ["--memory=3g"]
   - ["--memory=\"3g\""]
   - ["--memory-reservation=3g"]
2. Setting a ulimit in my Dockerfile, for the user that later runs the chown command.
3. Deleting all images and containers in Docker host, to force --no-cache (which I haven't found how to inject it neither :-/ )

**HELP!** Nothing works... Someone has any clue as to what could I do to prevent the container to consume all the memory from the server?

**Repo with config:** https://github.com/gsusI/vscode-remote_dev-config_test

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone find themselves in the same infinite loop. I found what's the issue!!

It appears that **runArgs** is not used when using docker-compose, hence configurations here have no effect.

*I know!! You'll expect a warning somewhere, right?*

**The next best option** is to do this through the docker-compose.yml file, right? Well, this is only true if you're using docker-composer version 2, as version 3 would only work with Docker swarm. In my case, I switched to version 2, and now everything works smoothly.

**TL;DR**

Your `docker-compose.yml` file should look like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  <your-service-name>:

    ...

    mem_limit: 2g
    mem_reservation: 2g
```

Check this for syntax hints: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources

Answer (score 3):

you just need to set gb instead of g:

```
"runArgs": [
    "--network=bridge",
    "--memory=6gb"],
```

This works for me fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DockerFile, then you can use the below code to increase the memory used by the container.

```
{
    "name" : "ProjectName",
    "build" : {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },

    "runArgs": [
        "--gpus", "all",
        "--shm-size=50gb" // gb or mb
    ],
}
```

Using `--memory` had no impact on the docker container.
This has worked successfully for me.

You can refer more information from https://datawookie.dev/blog/2021/11/shared-memory-docker/.